# Can OpenLayers.Protocol.Script be used to load a KML file?

Tags: openlayers, kml

I am trying to load a KML file and am thinking OpenLayers.Protocol.Script might be used to get around the cross-domain issue I am facing.  Does anyone know if that can be done, and if so, how?

I've seen examples of using it to load RSS feeds and other things, but not KML.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a proxy as explained [here](http://trac.osgeo.org/openlayers/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#HowdoIsetupaProxyHost). Then you can simply use a `new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP()`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, see OL example http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/cross-origin-xml.html 
to use the script protocol with YQL